# What happens to consumer groups in Kafka if the entire cluster goes down?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

We have a consumer service that is always trying to read data from a topic using a consumer group. Due to redeployments, our Kafka cluster periodically is brought down and recreated again.

Whenever the cluster comes back again, we observed that although the previous topics are picked up (probably from zookeeper), the previous consumer groups are not created. Because of this, our running consumer process which is created with a previous consumer group gets stuck and never comes out.

Is this how the behavior of the consumer groups should be or is there a configuration we need to enable somewhere?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Brokers keep a cache of healthy consumers and consumer groups, if the entire cluster is destroyed/recreated it no longer has knowledge of those consumers and groups, including offsets. The consumers will have to reconnect and re-establish the group and offsets from the beginning of the topic.

Operationally it makes more sense to keep the Kafka cluster running long-term, and do [version upgrades](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/upgrade.html) in a [rolling fashion](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#rolling-restart) so you don't interrupt the service.

Comment: These restarts are happening in our dev environment. That's why it was getting redeployed. `The consumers will have to reconnect and re-establish the group and offsets from the beginning of the topic` - The consumer is trying to reconnect again using the same consumer group. Shouldn't that work? I would assume that the new connection should create this consumer group again, at least with a zero offset. But that is not happening.

Comment: If the entire cluster is being destroyed, it will have no knowledge of any previous consumer groups. It doesn't matter if you specify the same consumer group details; as far as the cluster is concerned, it's never heard of this consumer group, and so will have to start afresh with a brand new group.

Comment: I understand that the cluster will not have any knowledge of the previous consumer group. But shouldn't a new consumer group be created when the existing consumer tries to connect with the new cluster? Right now, when this happens that consumer gets stuck.